# does createAsyncThunk create a Thunk

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-toolkit

I was Reading the Redux Docs I was a bit confused with createAsyncThunk

1. does createAsyncThunk create A thunk
2. are thunk and createAsyncThunk  completely two different Things
3. does createAsyncThunk Replace Thunk?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it really does what its name suggests.

- thunk is the name of the middleware that allows action creators to return functions instead of plain objects. These functions are called with helpful things like `dispatch` and `getState` as arguments, so you can orchestrate how other actions are dispatched, wait for asynchronous things, etc..
- Actions creators that return a function instead of an object are also called thunks when the thunk middleware is used in a project
- `createAsyncThunk` does not replace thunk, it is a more concise way of writing a thunk. They typically follow the same pattern so `createAsyncThunk` automates that away. `createAsyncThunk` in fact requires the thunk middleware to be used, which is taken care of by the store setup from redux-toolkit (where `createAsyncThunk` comes from).

Comment: so when i use createAsyncThunk i don't have to pass a thunk function to the store  like this for Example `store.dispatch(logAndAdd(5)` because createAsyncThunk create a Thunk Function automatically am i right ?

Comment: No the way you dispatch actions does not change. You'd still do `dispatch(logAndAdd(5))`. `createAsyncThunk` is only used to define the function, not to call it.

Answer (score 0):

`thunk` is a piece of code performing a delayed computation.

In redux-toolkit async requests are created with `createAsyncThunk`. Normally redux supports only synchronous data flow. If you need to make ajax request and dispatch the result of this request, then you need to use middlewares that handles the async operations.

Before redux-toolkit, `redux-thunk` package was installed. Redux-toolkit makes state management more efficient with less code and less packages.